# Scrollable band of images, and other things inside screen using MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am looking for sample code, documentation, or even a third party control I could use to do the following.

I'd like to create a band on my iOS screen that only takes up part of the screen.  This could be scrollable left and right.  The content inside the band would be information.  Icons.  Pictures.  Etc.  Each item would be clickable as well.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

This component is called CoverFlow. Apple restricts use of their own API, so there are some open-source libraries. One of them is OpenFlow and you can find it here: http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/

The good thing about it - it was ported to C# a while ago. Here you can find MonoTouch port of this library: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/OpenFlowSharp

And it's free to use in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what i am looking for.  I think cover flow worked fine when scrolling through albums on my iPod, but I am looking for something a bit more elegant.  I don't want the flip view at all.  Just square images placed throughout the canvas of the control I will build that will be scrollable left and right by the user.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend watching [Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=223)* from WWDC 2012.

The speaker discusses using a UIScrollView and UIPageViewController.  Your case sounds simpler since you don't want to zoom.

In iOS 6 a new transition style was added to the Page View Controller, so you can scroll between "pages" instead of "curling."

See [Transition Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle) in the beta documentation:

> **UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll**
>   Scrolling transition style.
>   When the page scrolling style is specified, the page view controller
>   displays a page-scrolling animation when transitioning between view
>   controllers. If a data source is specified, the animation follows the
>   user’s finger during a navigation gesture. Available in iOS 6.0 and
>   later.

At this time, I have not tried using iOS 6 and MonoTouch.  See this announcement with respect to using iOS 6 with MonoTouch: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/06/15/xcode-4-5-ios-6-and-mountain-lion/

*Requires developer access.